# How to interpret Visual Studio / TFS reference count (VS2015, C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

Sometimes, the reference count in Visual Studio 2015 doesn't make sense to me.

Let's take the screenshot below as an example:
The class is the "code behind" of an ASP.NET Web Forms page, which inherits a custom base page.

The OnInit method of this class is said to have 140 references, but in fact it's not likely to have more than one, is it..? The *BasePage's* OnInit might possibly have 140 references, or even more likely the Page class that BasePage inherits, but not the one in *this* unique class; "ArticlePage".

It almost seems as if Visual Studio happily considers any reference to any method named "OnInit" as a reference to this particular method - which seems plainly wrong to me.

Can anyone explain how the reference count, and the associated reference links, are to be interpreted in a case like this?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at jessehouwing's answer in this post : [Incorrect codelens references in VS 2013 ultimate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32169280/incorrect-codelens-references-in-vs-2013-ultimate) (after some test, logic is the same between vs2013 and vs2015)

Comment: Thanks! To summarize the answer Jérémy links to, it seems the reference count and links are a bit of a trade off, where the count includes items that might be references, along with things that definitely are references. Instead of displaying these separately from each other, the are presented together for ...well, UI simplicity I guess.